# Convergence of $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\exp({-1/x)}}{\sqrt{ \sin x}}\, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

Let $$f(x)=\frac{\exp(-1/x)}{\sqrt{ \sin x}}\, \mathrm{d}x.$$

$f(x)$ seems to not have any problems at $x=\frac {\pi}{2}$, but at $x=0$.
So I should understand behavior of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ by evaluating $\lim_{x\to0+}f(x)$.But I am stuck here as I can't apply Taylor expansions to $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ and using l'Hospital's rule gives me nothing.

Comment: You could try squaring $f$ first, then compute the limit at $0$.

Comment: @user170231 what exactly lets us squaring $f$ and then take the limit?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $e^{1/x}\ge 1+\frac1x$ for $x>0$ and $x\cos(x)\le \sin(x)$ for $x\in [0,\pi/2]$.

Hence for $x\in(0,\pi/2]$, we have

$$0\le \frac{e^{-1/x}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\le \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac 1x\right) \sqrt{x\cos(x)}}=\frac{\sqrt x}{x+1}\sqrt{\frac{
1}{\cos(x)}} $$

Now apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Can you please explain your comment on my answer, since your comment is not constructive?

Comment: @viktorglombik For example, your use of LHR after you wrote "Now we can apply ..." makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: You can apply LHR if the limit of the quotient of derivatives exists.  Have you shown this here?  The limit does exist and is $0$, but you haven't shown this.  At best your development is convoluted.  And writing $L=2(\infty)^2$ is definitely nonsense.

Comment: I have shown $f(x) \to \infty$, so $\frac{1}{f(x)} \to 0$ follows, when minding the appropriate restrictions. If you have a good idea on improving my answer, please edit it! We're all here to learn, after all.

Comment: Viktor I don't have time to rewrite your post.

Comment: I added some steps for my use of LHR after I wrote "Now we can apply ...", hoping this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Using the continuity of the square root, we can conclude
\begin{equation*}
I
:=\lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}
= \sqrt{ \lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{e^{-\frac{2}{x}}}{\sin(x)}}
= \sqrt{ \lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{1}{e^{\frac{2}{x}} \sin(x)}}
\end{equation*}
Now, we can apply L'Hôpital to the following limit
\begin{equation*}
L
:= \lim_{x \searrow 0} e^{\frac{2}{x}} \sin(x)
= \lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{e^{-\frac{2}{x}}}
= \lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{ \frac{d}{d x}\sin(x)}{\frac{d}{d x} e^{-\frac{2}{x}}}
= \lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{\cos(x)}{\frac{2}{x^2} e^{-\frac{2}{x}}}
= \lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{x^2}{2} \cos(x) \cdot e^{\frac{2}{x}}.
\end{equation*}
And now, because the limits of the factors exist and one is finite we have by the product rule
\begin{equation*}
L = \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\lim_{x \searrow 0} \cos(x)}_{= 1} \cdot \left(\lim_{x \searrow 0} x^2 \cdot e^{\frac{2}{x}}\right)
= \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\left(\lim_{x \searrow 0} x^2 \cdot e^{\frac{2}{x}}\right)}_{:= \widetilde{L}}
\end{equation*}

Since $x \mapsto x^2$ is monotone and continuous, we have
\begin{equation*}
\widetilde{L}
= \big( \underbrace{\lim_{x \searrow 0} x \cdot e^{\frac{1}{x}}}_{=: \widehat{L}} \big)^2
\end{equation*}
Now, by L'Hôpital, we have
\begin{equation*}
\widehat{L}
= \lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{1}{x}}
= \lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x}}
= \lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{-\frac{1}{x^2} e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}
= \lim_{x \searrow 0} e^{\frac{1}{x}}
= \infty.
\end{equation*}

Therefore, we have $L = \infty$ and so $I = 0$.

Comment: This makes no sense.